# Spark structured streaming over google cloud storage

Tags: apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, google-cloud-dataproc, spark-structured-streaming

I am running few batch Spark pipelines that consumes Avro data on google cloud storage. I need to update some pipelines to be more realtime and wondering if spark structured streaming can directly consume files from gcs in a streaming way i.e `parkContext.readstream.from(...)` can be applied to Avro files that are being generated continuously under a bucket from external sources.

Apache beam already has something like `File.MatchAll().continuously()`, Watch, `watchnewFiles` that allow beam pipelines to monitor for new files and read them in a streaming way (thus obviating the need of pubsub or notification system) , is there something similar for Spark structured streaming as well ?

Answer (score 1):

As the GCS connector exposes a Hadoop-Compatible FileSystem (HCFS), "gs://" URIs should be valid targets for SparkSession.readStream.from.

Avro file handling is implemented by [spark-avro](https://github.com/databricks/spark-avro). Using it with readStream should be accomplished the same way as generic reading (e.g., `.format("com.databricks.spark.avro")`)

Comment: Thanks. Could you please also tell if reading stream of files like this is exactly once (as opposed to putting them in kafka queue) ? If my streaming job fails and restart another one , will i read only new files generated after job is started or is there a way for me to read old "unprocessed" files that were generated between the pipeline failure and restart ? Do i need to set any checkpointing or configuration to enable this

Comment: Yes, you'll want to enable metadata checkpointing: https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/streaming-programming-guide.html#how-to-configure-checkpointing

Comment: https://github.com/jaceklaskowski/spark-structured-streaming-book/blob/master/spark-sql-streaming-DataStreamReader.adoc#format : iyt seems like avro is not supported , can you please confirm